# Unity Oculus LipSync Demo is not available on the Ios App Store

Tags: ios, lipsync

I built an Ios App of Oculus LipSync through Unity,but it won't be available in the IOS App Store.

And it replied：ITMS-90426: Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.

What is the cause of this problem?  And how can I fix it?

I hope to get some advice and help.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems like you are using an outdated Xcode version. update and try again